# php/mysql : Is it possible to add one to the field without selecting from db?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code...

```
$q = "SELECT count FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "count WHERE 1 LIMIT 1;";
        $r = mysql_query($q);

        if (!$r) {
            echo $q;
            return false;
        }

        $o = mysql_fetch_object($r);
        $count = $o->count + 1;

    $q = "UPDATE " . TABLE_PREFIX . "count SET `count` = {$count}";
```

As you can see it selects field from db(its just a number) and adds 1 to it before sending it back to db...

Is it possible to skip the selecting part and instead just say something like:

```
`SET `count` += 1`
```

or something like that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
update TABLE_PREFIX set count = count + 1 where {condition}
```

Comment: I believe that this does answer the question. It increments count by 1 while skipping the `select` query and the PHP logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. you can update the column without fetching and increment to this field

```
UPDATE tablename set `count` = (`count`+1) WHERE 1 LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: `COUNT` is a reserved word; so using backticks is highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = "UPDATE " . TABLE_PREFIX . "count SET `count` = `count`+1 ";
```

Comment: @kenorb why this is not an answer to the question?

Comment: It's missing explanation (e.g. why and what does it do) or some short introduction text to improve the quality of your answer, otherwise further readers can't learn from it and easily understand your answer (as it's out of context). The same apply for other similar answers in this thread.

Answer (score -1):

Basically:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `count` = `count`+1;
```